# MySql giving syntax error after Gson serialization

Tags: java, mysql, gson, syntax-error

I seem to have a problem with Gson serialization. After the serialization when i try to save it into the database I receive a syntax error from mysql.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''{"nexus_loc":{"world":"world","x":300.0,"y":63.0,"z":428.0,"pitch":0.0,"yaw":0.' at line 1
```

Here is the code for saving function.

```
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO %table VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `data` = VALUES(?)".replace("%table",tablename));
            stmt.setString(1,key);
            stmt.setString(2,serialize(value,type));
            stmt.setString(3,serialize(value,type));
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            stmt.close();
```

This is the string with which we create the table

```
        String tablequery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %table (`id` CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY, `data` TEXT);".replace("%table",tablename);
```

Comment: What is the exact SQL you are executing after you modify the string? What is the content of the values you are passing to `setString`?

Comment: Could you please provide code of serialize method? Seems like you are adding unnecessary leading and trailing qoutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VALUES()` is not needed in the `UPDATE` part.

So instead of

```
"INSERT INTO %table VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `data` = VALUES(?)"`
```

Try

```
"INSERT INTO %table VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `data` = ?"
```

Comment: Fixed the issue. It's weird tho it didn't work with values but functioned normal without it.